# htaccess redirect to another folder

Tags: .htaccess

I have to redirect using `htaccess`.Please help me.
From this 
`URL :- http://xxx/CCKCHT/` 
to redirect it

```
URL :- http://xxx/CCKCHT/lhc_web/index.php/site_admin/
```

Comment: So you want to redirect from: `/CCKCHT/foo` to `/CCKCHT/lhc_web/index.php/site_admin/foo` ?

Comment: @anubhava  yes i want this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /CCKCHT/

RewriteRule (?!^lhc_web/index\.php/site_admin/)^(.*)$ /CCKCHT/lhc_web/index.php/site_admin/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: What URI did you use to test?

Comment: Ok, make sure you have mod_rewrite and .htaccess enabled? Also let me know what happens when you visit: `http://xxx/CCKCHT/lhc_web/index.php/site_admin/` ? Also try this ina  different browser.